# "Inconsequent" and "inconsequential"

Tags: word-choice, differences

What is the difference between "inconsequent" and "inconsequential"?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

None, it seems *inconsequent* is the archaic form of *inconsequential* as stated by [Wikipedia](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/inconsequent).